# position of included figure inside a itemize element

Tags: floats, itemize, includegraphics

I need to include a figure inside a itemize element, like:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item Some text \includegraphics[width=0.2\linediwidth]{figure}
\item etc
\end{itemize}
```

How to I control the vertical position of the figure inside the line? Ideally, I would like to have the figure vertically centered.

Comment: use `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` then `\includegraphics` will get a valign key to specify vertical alignment and you can use `valign=c`

Comment: There is also `\raisebox` for fine control, although the actual shifts for `valign=c` and `valign=t` can be complicated due to offsets of the baseline relative to text.